# Show Elements Base on Property using *ngIf

Tags: angular, ngfor

for reference this is the tutorial that I am watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qCAVg0pvVg

in the db-data.ts I only want to show the course-card that containts a specifc property for example course.category == ADVANCE. how can I achieve this in the HTML file

I tried this code snippet but its not working

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let course of courses" >
    <div *ngIf="course.description == JORDAN">
        <div class="courses"  >
          <course-card  (courseSelected)="onCourseSelected($event)" [course]="course">

          </course-card>
        </div>
      </div>

</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the string within **`quotes(''`**) and use **`===`** to do the type check as follows,

```
 <div *ngIf="course.description === 'JORDAN'">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*ngIf="course.category == 'ADVANCE'"
```

It Will work in that case. place single quotes on text to match.